# Characteristic exponent random variable well-defined?

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, logarithms, characteristic-functions

Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. We define the characteristic exponent of $X$ by

$$\Psi(u) := -\log\mathbb{E}(e^{iuX})$$

Is this well-defined? How are we sure that we don't get something like $-\log(-1)$ (assuming principal branch of logarithm) and get something undefined?

Comment: What is the domain of $\Psi$? In case it's $\mathbb{R}$, it may be helpful (or not) to remind that you $e^{iuX}$ "lives" on the unit circle.

Comment: It is $\mathbb{R}$, but even then, it can be possible to be well-defined no? For example, take $X=1$. Then $\Psi(u) = - \log (e^{iu})$ and $\Psi(\pi) = - \log(e^{i \pi}) = - \log(-1)$, which is undefined.

Comment: @user7427029 why not defined? $\Psi(u)$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}$ but it is valued in  $\mathbb{C}$, so $log(-1)=i\,\pi$, correct?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem when the characteristic function vanishes at some point. Otherwise there is a unique continuous function $\Psi$ such that $\Psi(0)=0$ and $e^{-\Psi (t)}=Ee^{itX}$ for all $t$. For a proof of this see Theorem 7.6.2 in Chung's book [applied to each of the intervals $[-N,N]$.